# Run GDB 'commands' command from terminal?

Tags: gdb

According to [this page](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Break-Commands.html), it is possible to have specific commands executed in GDB on breakpoint. Example from the linked page:

```
break foo if x>0
commands
silent
printf "x is %d\n",x
cont
end
```

What the above means is break on function `foo` if `x>0`, print the value of `x` and continue with the execution.

Is there a way to specify `commands...end` from the terminal line? Something like:

`gdb -ex=r -ex=bt -ex='b foo commands silent... end' --args myprog`

Googling for the term `gdb commands` leads to a lot of ambiguity and I am not able to find a working example. Thank you.

Comment: Write commands to a file and use `-x`.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. Your comment made me look up the use of files to store GDB commands, and because of that I discovered the `save breakpoints [filename]` command. It allows you to store breakpoint info in a file, including `commands` entries, and later load it via `-ex='source filename'`. So in a way, thank you.